# Cosmological or Doppler redshift in distance calculations

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, cosmology

If I want to determine the distance to a far away galxy with a high redshift,
then using relativistic doppler shift will not give the true distance as it
does not take into account the expansion of the universe due to general relativity. Then why do we even
need special relativity in distance calculations? Even at University classes,
distances are calculated with sp.relativistic redshift, so how should we
interpret those results?

To put some numbers on it. Say I want the distance to a galaxy with redshift z=2. This is high enough for relativistic corrections and so the Hubble Law $v = H_0d$ is combined with its recession speed to find the distance, which is: $$d = \frac{c}{H_0}\frac{(z+1)^2-1}{(z+1)^2+1}$$

For $z=2$ and $H_0=70 ~kms^{-1}Mpc^{-1}$ we find this distance to be approximately 11 billion light years. But since this is supposedly wrong, then what exactly IS this distance? Is the purpose of this calculation only to serve as an exercise in special relativity? Does the 11 billion light years actually have some physical meaning, or is it just a fantasy figure? I'm reading something about $peculiar ~motion$ and wonder if that could be it, this galaxy is 11 billion l.y. away relative to $us$ only in our rest frame?

I don't have much experience in General Relativity, but if I have understood it correctly then the above calculation is valid only in a flat Universe where the Hubble parameter $H(t)$ is constant in time?

From what I understand, in General Relativity the scale factor is important here. From the Robertson-Walker metric, it can be shown that: $$1+z = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda_0} = \frac{a(t)}{a(t_0)}$$

And from our case with $z=2$ and setting $a(t)=1$ we find a scale factor $a(t_0)=\frac{1}{3}$, telling us the galaxy emitted this light we see when the Universe was a third of the size today. But how do I go about finding the distance?

Using the distance to a comoving object: $d_c = c\int_{t_0}^t\frac{dt}{a(t)}$ combined with the velocity-distance relation gives $v=cH_0\int_{0}^z\frac{dz'}{H(z')}$

I can work out other details later, but for now I want to focus on a flat Universe with a Hubble parameter that is constant in time, to see if I have at least got that right.
But for an expanding Universe with an unchanging $H$, then $H(z') = H_0$ and the integral above reduces to $v=zc$. (which holds for all $z$ and not just an approximation for small $z$ as it is before bringing in GR)

Thus when $H_0$ is constant in time, general relativity dictates that the recession speed for our $z=2$ galaxy is $2c$ and the distance $d=\frac{v}{H_0}$ is about 28 billion l.y. when this light receives us (which means the galaxy has left the Hubble sphere). But because of the scale factor $a(t)=\frac{1}{3}$ the distance was $\frac{28}{3}$ billion l.y. when the light was emitted.

I feel like I'm just barely hanging on to this. I can't really distinguish what is the comoving distance, or the proper distance. If the latter calculations happen to be somewhat correct, then what about the sp.relativistic calculation I did in the beginning? Does that have no place here at all, or should it somehow be combined with the proper distance and/or comoving distance that is found from general relativity?

Been reading about this for days now and it's like I'm just reading in circles. Perhaps someone could sum it up for me and help me discern what is what. If I just understood the simplest case with unchanging $H$ and a flat universe (and presumably no matter in it) it will be easier later since I don't have much problem with the mathematics behind it, it's the physics that confuses me.

Comment: It isn't a question of whether to use special relativity or general relativity. SR is built into the structure of GR. Using GR always means you are implicitly using SR.

Comment: With SR I get 11Bly to this z=2 galaxy and with GR I get 28Bly. I don't doubt what you're saying, but shouldn't the 11Bly come up somehow when using GR? That's what I was trying to get to all along.